ClosedXML apply already existing conditional formatting to inserted data
I'm looking to a way to apply already existing conditional formatting to data which are being inserted with InserData() method. If I apply the same style to new range it doesn't apply the conditional formatting. I can create new conditional formatting but I would like to use already existing as this is a template excel file.
